# Is it possible for two SQL transactions to interleave on read?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, transactions, acid

I'm trying to understand ACID properties and how they affect how we think about concurrency in an ACID database. Let's say I have a table `accounts` with `account_id` and `balance` field, and I have three rows in the database:

```
account_id | balance
-----------|--------
         1 | 100
         2 | 0
         3 | 0
```

Now suppose I run the following transactions concurrently:

```
start transaction;
if (select balance from accounts where account_id = 1) >= 100 {
    update accounts set balance = 100 where account_id = 2;
    update accounts set balance = 0 where account_id = 1;
}
commit transaction;
```

and

```
start transaction;
if (select balance from accounts where account_id = 1) >= 100 {
    update accounts set balance = 100 where account_id = 3;
    update accounts set balance = 0 where account_id = 1;
}
commit transaction;
```

Note that the first updates account 2, and the second updates account 3.
Is it possible that the table ends up in the following state:

```
account_id | balance
-----------|--------
         1 | 0
         2 | 100
         3 | 100
```

In other words, is it possible that the balance is double spent? Let's assume we are using SQL server.

Comment: Are you wanting to talk "pure" ACID or are you thinking about a specific database system? If the latter, please identify which system you're interested in. For instance, with SQL Server, the answer depends a lot on the transaction isolation level of each transaction.

Comment: Also, for practical purposes, a single `UPDATE` statement that updates both accounts if the source account has sufficient balance would be preferred.

Comment: Your statements consist of four separate `update`s.  There are no transactions defined, and most databases treat a single statement as a transaction in that case.  These could be run in multiple orders:  1-2-3-4; 1-3-2-4, 3-4-1-2, 1-3-4-2, 3-1-2-4, or 3-1-4-2 (I don't think I missed any).  So, there could be a variety of results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, I meant to add a `start transaction` and `commit transaction` at the beginning and end of each of those code blocks.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever let's say I'm interested in SQL server. I will update the question. But I am also interested to know the answer for "pure" ACID as well.

Comment: @shmth . . . Where the transaction begins and ends is very important to the question.  You should either edit the question or delete this question and ask a new, more complete one.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've updated the question

Comment: I think the balance could be double-spent.  Assuming that the initial read locks can co-exist and do not block then I see no reason why the updates in both cases could not be actioned, and are more likely to succeed if the write locks are taken at row level.  
I think that there is an expectation that blocking operations fail instantly when blocked.  This is not necessarily the case.  There is often a waiting time allowance for blocking queries to complete before a blocked query is aborted.

Comment: I'm quite sure it could happen. 'SELECT ... FOR UPDATE' is amongst other things there to prevent that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible for two SQL transactions to interleave on read?

Yes.

Different DBMSs may use different approaches to dealing with concurrency. ACID is not the full picture. SQL standard also defines several so called transaction isolation levels. These levels and their implementation in a specific DBMS (row versioning or locking) would define what happens in your example.

By default SQL Server uses `READ COMMITTED` [transaction isolation level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) without row versioning.

At this level it is easy to double-spend the account balance.

I used this helper stored procedure in the code below to print messages in the SSMS Messages pane:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DebugPrintMessage]
    @ParamMessage nvarchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    -- Escape the % symbol in the message, if it is there
    SET @ParamMessage = REPLACE(@ParamMessage, '%', '%%');

    -- Prepend message with the current timestamp to a second precision
    SET @ParamMessage = CONVERT(nvarchar(19), SYSDATETIME(), 121) + ' ' + @ParamMessage;

    RAISERROR (@ParamMessage, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;

    -- PRINT command does not send the message to the client until its buffer is full, or the batch ends
    -- RAISERROR () WITH NOWAIT sends a message immediately

END
GO
```

I opened two windows/connections/sessions in SSMS and put your code in each window. (One window updated ID=2, another ID=3, I'm not repeating it here)

```
EXEC dbo.DebugPrintMessage 'waiting to start';
-- round up the current time to the next 30 seconds
DECLARE @StartDateTime datetime2(0) = SYSDATETIME();
SET @StartDateTime = DATEADD(second, (DATEDIFF(second, '2020-01-01', @StartDateTime) / 30 + 1) * 30, '2020-01-01');
DECLARE @StartTimeString varchar(8);
SET @StartTimeString = CONVERT(varchar(8), @StartDateTime, 108);
WAITFOR TIME @StartTimeString;

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
--SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
--SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
EXEC dbo.DebugPrintMessage 'began transaction';
IF (select balance from accounts where ID = 1) >= 100
BEGIN
    EXEC dbo.DebugPrintMessage 'waiting 2 sec';
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';

    EXEC dbo.DebugPrintMessage 'first update';
    UPDATE dbo.Accounts
    SET Balance = 100
--  WHERE ID = 2
    WHERE ID = 3
    ;

    EXEC dbo.DebugPrintMessage 'second update';
    UPDATE dbo.Accounts
    SET Balance = 0
    WHERE ID = 1
    ;
END
EXEC dbo.DebugPrintMessage 'waiting for review';
WAITFOR DELAY '00:01:00';
EXEC dbo.DebugPrintMessage 'committing';
COMMIT;
```

Both transactions completed successfully and two accounts had balance of 100 in the end.

The output shows how it was executed:

**Session 1**

```
2021-03-29 19:12:13 waiting to start
2021-03-29 19:12:30 began transaction
2021-03-29 19:12:30 waiting 2 sec
2021-03-29 19:12:32 first update

(1 row affected)
2021-03-29 19:12:32 second update

(1 row affected)
2021-03-29 19:12:32 waiting for review
2021-03-29 19:13:32 committing
```

**Session 2**

```
2021-03-29 19:12:11 waiting to start
2021-03-29 19:12:30 began transaction
2021-03-29 19:12:30 waiting 2 sec
2021-03-29 19:12:32 first update

(1 row affected)
2021-03-29 19:12:32 second update

(1 row affected)
2021-03-29 19:13:32 waiting for review
2021-03-29 19:14:32 committing
```

We can see that session 1 did both updates without any extra waits. Session 2 did the first update together with S1, but on the second update waited for the first session to commit (because it was attempting to update the same row with ID=1). S2 continued only after S1 finished its transaction. Pay attention to timestamps after the message "second update".

---

I then tried this example with the transaction isolation level set to `REPEATABLE READ` and to `SERIALIZABLE`. One transaction completed and another was aborted with this message:

> Msg 1205, Level 13, State 51, Line 13 Transaction (Process ID 55) was
> deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen
> as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

So, there was no double-spend under these more strict transaction isolation levels.

**Session 1**

```
2021-03-29 19:27:12 waiting to start
2021-03-29 19:27:30 began transaction
2021-03-29 19:27:30 waiting 2 sec
2021-03-29 19:27:32 first update

(1 row affected)
2021-03-29 19:27:32 second update

(1 row affected)
2021-03-29 19:27:32 waiting for review
2021-03-29 19:28:32 committing
```

**Session 2**

```
2021-03-29 19:27:10 waiting to start
2021-03-29 19:27:30 began transaction
2021-03-29 19:27:30 waiting 2 sec
2021-03-29 19:27:32 first update

(1 row affected)
2021-03-29 19:27:32 second update
Msg 1205, Level 13, State 51, Line 27
Transaction (Process ID 55) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

Note here that a more strict transaction isolation level did not stop two transactions from reading the same row twice. The `SELECT` completed in both sessions without problems. It did not stop them from updating different rows. It is only when it got to updating the same row with `ID=1`, the conflict arose.

In general, it is better to try update of the `ID = 1` with `balance = 0` before updating the balance of another account. If you swap the `UPDATE` statements, one of the transactions will be aborted sooner and there will be less work to roll back.

Or, use locking hints on `SELECT` or `sp_getapplock` or some other method to avoid concurrency.

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity, what do "pure" ACID principle say should actually happen in this scenario?

Comment: Your example focuses on `I` in ACID. "pure" ACID would be the strictest interpretation of the Isolation property. It means that DBMS should behave in such a way as if transactions were run in a sequence, not simultaneously. In practice [Of the four ACID properties in a DBMS, the isolation property is the one most often relaxed.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)) And this is when all these transaction isolation levels become into play. This Wikipedia article explains all this pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this answer with SQL Server v14.0 (using SSMS). It's working, if both transactions have the same config:

First transaction (locking one, using waitfor for give me time to test):

```
BEGIN TRAN;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
SELECT * FROM accounts WITH (XLOCK, ROWLOCK) WHERE account_id = 1;
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';
UPDATE accounts SET balance = 0 WHERE account_id = 1;
COMMIT TRAN;
```

Second transaction (locked one in this case, doing only read):

```
BEGIN TRAN;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
SELECT * FROM accounts WITH (XLOCK, ROWLOCK) WHERE account_id = 1;
COMMIT TRAN;
```

The second one wait if the first one is still running. Perhaps you can adapt these code for using it (Question doesn't give information about the system / language you're using).

Key on this are: First, set the isolation level. Second, set the XLOCK (Exclusive lock) on the select, and also, ROWLOCK for locking only these row, no page or table.

I hope this answer works for you.